# Why does gruntjs file array format not allow referencing dest files in another task using templates?

Tags: gruntjs

I ran into an issue with a new build I am creating with gruntjs.  I wanted to use grunt-contrib-copy to copy files into my deployment area and then reuse those destination files in a later task.  It looks like I should be able to reference task destination files using a template as described in the [Grunt: Configuring Tasks](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) documentation.  But when I use this with a file array format specified source task it does not work.

I have created a gist that shows the problem: [Grunt File Array Example Gist](https://gist.github.com/abierbaum/5065053)

Reproduction:

1. git clone https://gist.github.com/5065053.git test_example
2. cd test_example
3. npm install
4. ./node_modules/.bin/grunt
5. See how the output from debug_files tasks don't have files for dests of items specified with file array syntax.

It is likely that I am just doing something wrong, but I can't seem to track it down.  Does anyone see my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the templates simply cannot fetch values from arrays. I had a similar problem and worked around it by creating a standard JS variable in my Gruntfile (after all it's a standard JS file).

Still you may want to try: <%= concat.prod.files.0.dest %>, which I'm not able to try at the moment.